# Vim syntastic for C does not show warning for unused-function

Tags: vim, syntastic

When I run the Syntastic syntax check on my C file I do not get warnings about unused-function.

When I run

```
:let g:syntastic_c_compiler_options
```

I get

```
-DUSE_STM32L476G_EVAL_REVB -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32L476xx -DDEBUG_CODE -I./Core/Inc -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Include -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Drivers/BSP/Components -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Drivers/CMSIS/Include -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Drivers/BSP/Components/stmpe1600 -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Drivers/BSP/Components/stmpe811 -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Drivers/BSP/STM32L476G_EVAL -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/MSC/Inc -IC:/ST/STM32Cube_FW_L4_V1.13.0/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc -I./Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I./Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I./Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Include -I./Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I./FATFS/Target -I./FATFS/App -I./Application/Src -I./Application/Inc -I./Middlewares/Third_Party/FatFs/src -Wall
```

(notice it ends with `-Wall`).

When I run

```
:SyntasticInfo
```

I get

```
Syntastic version: 3.8.0-14 (Vim 800, Windows, GUI)
Info for filetype: c
Global mode:active
Filetype c is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Avaiable checkrs: gcc make
Currently enabled check: gcc
```

I know that syntastic is working because I do get other warnings, however, I do not get warning for unused-function (i.e. `static int foo() {}` that no one calls).
When I run on the command line.

```
$ gcc -....(all the options mentioned above) -c myfile.c
```

I do see those warnings.

Comment: Turn on debugging (`:h syntastic-debug`) in order to see what command actually gets run.